# Symfony: ошибка "Method not allowed (405)" при отправке формы

Tags: php, symfony, html-form

Есть очень простая html-форма (используется шаблонизатор Twig):

```
<form action="{{ path('simple_route') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
    <input type="text" name=simple-input">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

И соответствующий обработчик для метода PUT:

```
#[Route(path: '/simple-route', name: 'simple_route', methods: ['PUT'])]
public function simpleRoute(): Response
{
    // ...
}
```

В [документации Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#matching-http-methods) сказано, что для того, чтобы отправить метод PUT, нужно в html-форму добавить скрытое поле `_method`. Как видно на примере формы, я это сделал. Однако я всё равно получаю ошибку:

```
No route found for "POST http://example.com/simple-route: Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT)
```

Не могу понять, как в Symfony отправить форму на обработчик, который слушает методы, отличающиеся от стандартных GET/POST. Если кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой ошибки.

P.S. Использую PHP 8.1 и Symfony 6.0.2.

Comment: У вас в форме написано `method="post"` замените `post` на `put`.

Comment: Это был один из первых вариантов, которые я тестировал. Если в форме указано что-то, отличающееся от post или get, то в таком случае считается, что в method указан get (поведение по умолчанию). Поэтому такая форма отправляется не через post или put, а через get, что, конечно же, совершенно неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось, необходимо было добавить параметр `http_method_override` в файл конфигурации фреймворка (`config/packages/framework.yaml`):

```
framework:
  http_method_override: true
```

Протестировано на Symfony 6.0.4.